# List Alphabet A-Z in Smarty

Tags: foreach, smarty, alphabet

I was searching for the web, but I only found a smarty plugin function for displaying the Alphabet from A to Z.

There are cases, when you couldn't add a new plugin, so how could you display it otherwise?

Comment: Can you provide a clear example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You could see a detailed description in the first answers comment list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy with pure smarty foreach.

```
    {foreach item=i from='A'|@range:'Z'}
        {$i}
    {/foreach}
```

Comment: But with your option how would you apply dynamic data ?
If I need a Letter list for a Glossary, I need the letters, not the letter's list in a string.
I mean e.g: <a name="{$i}">{if $letter->isActive($i)}{$i}{/if}</a>

Comment: In this case your solution would be better. I just wanted to write an alternative for the initial issue :)